# Auto increment column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an auto increment (id)column in my table.If i delete all data from my table and insert one new data into my table ,will it be continuing my id,or start again with 0??

Comment: it will continue

Comment: If you delete it will continue if you truncate it will start again with 1 (unless you have set auto_increment to start from 0)

Answer (score 0):

This is easily enough tested; [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=259e535aa0568ee388571370d80b8ad8) is a db<>fiddle.

I'm answer to provide some explanation:

- If you **`delete`** all rows, then the auto-increment value is not altered.
- If you **`truncate`** the table, then the auto-increment value is reset.

In general, truncating a table is a better way of emptying it, for the following reasons:

- Truncation does not log the transactions.  So, it is faster.  (This can be a downside, of course, if you want to recover the data.)
- Truncation does not call delete triggers.  (This can be a downside, of course, if you want these to be run.)
- Truncation simply disposes of the storage rather than treating each row independently.

Answer (score 0):

MySql database maintain Information schema where save next increment value....

```
select tab.TABLE_NAME, tab.AUTO_INCREMENT from information_schema.TABLES tab where tab.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema_name';
```

if execute that query it will show your next auto_increment id value.. if you execute delete query as

```
delete from table_name;
```

this query delete all data but not restore auto increment column value....
if you want to restore auto increment value to 1 .. execute `truncate` command

```
truncate table table_name;
```

you have another way to restore Auto_increment value by this query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

[for morde details](https://www.viralpatel.net/reseting-mysql-autoincrement-column/)